# Protractor tests timeout with error - Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test]

Tags: html, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have angular page which doesn't have `ng-app` directive.
I am trying to load an application using protractor 3.3.0 but it fails with error

> Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test].

Is there any method to resolve this error? Should I ask devs to change page or is there any workaround for this? Or Am I missing on something?

Please help!

Comment: Is it even possible for an angular app to not have the `ng-app` directive?  I don't think it would compile HTML without it... Anyway, if you don't have one, then you need to use `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` so Protractor does not wait for the `angular` variable.

Comment: Protractor will look for ng-app directive in body tag by default before start executing test scripts to confirm it is Angular application. If it not found, it will return error which you pasted above. If it's Angular application, it definitely have ng-app directive in any tag like <html> or <body> or <dev>. please confirm from you developers about it. If it's not Angular then you have to follow protractor syntax for Non Angular application. If ng-app placed in other tag not in body, you need to mention explicitly the location of ng-app directive 'rootElement:locator' in config file

Comment: @Gunderson That's where I was confused. But same html page has other angular directives like ng-scope, ng-include.